# How to use output of tMSSqlSP on a tJava element

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, talend

I have a `tMSSqlSP` element calling a procedure that receives two params and returns two values. If I connect a `tLogRow` right after that, I can see that the procedure is being called correctly and returning the correct values. However, I need to use those values in a `tJava` element, which means calling them explicitly somehow.

The schema for the `tMSSqlSP` looks like:

```
Column     Db Column
entityTIN   EntityTIN  (IN)
qtdDoc      QtdDoc     (IN)
nextMsg     NextMsg    (OUT)
nextDoc     NextDoc    (OUT)
```

The only global variable `tMSSqlSP` has is an error message, and I tried checking the "Is function" box and setting "Return result in" to `nextMsg`, but trying to use this variable on `tJava` results in compilation errors.

Any idea how I would go about accessing these values explicitly?

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of this section of the job. The `tLogRow` connected to the `tMSSqlSP`prints correctly the values of the two input variables and the two output variables, but the two deactivated components on the right are only able to see null values when connected.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link your `tMSSqlSP` component to a `tSetGlobalVar`, and add 2 global variables to it (NextMsg and NextDoc) that take their values from the column of your input flow (`rowX.column`).

You can then reference them in the next subjob by referencing them in a tJava like so : `(String)globalMap.get("NextMsg")`

If you need to process them in the same subjob as `tMSSqlSP`, you can instead connect `tMSSqlSP` to a `tJavaFlex` or a `tJavaRow` (as `tJava` doesn't handle input main flows) and just use something like `row18.NextMsg`.

Comment: The global variables are all being set to null... A tJava printing row18 also shows all variables as null... But if I disconnect that and replace it with a tLogRow I get the correct values???

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of your job ?

Comment: Added a screenshot